# Doctrine setParameter() not working for me on a simple expression. I receive '?'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

With this code:

```
$qb->select('user.id')->from('myVendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Users', 'user');
$expr = $qb->expr()->eq('user.email', '?1');
$qb->where($expr);
$qb->setParameter(1, 'testval');
```

I receive:

```sql
SELECT e0_.uid AS uid_0 FROM my_table e0_ WHERE e0_.email = ?
```

I also tried this:

```php
// ...
$expr = $qb->expr()->eq('user.email', ':test');
// ...
$qb->setParameter('test', 'testval');
```

PHP 5.5 | MSSQL | Doctrine\Dbal 2.5.1 | Doctrine\Orm 2.5.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine does not replace parameters in a query itself, it uses prepared statements which means that parameters are replaced(and escaped) by database server.

That is the reason why you always see parametrized (with question-marks) queries when you try to display it.

Comment: I comprehend that the params going handled as prepared statements. But is there a way to neverheless "parse" the values into the prepared statements for showing the full generated SQL? Such an "export as SQL" in my project is really a feature for the admin-users (until now reslized with literals but i want to use prepared statements).

Comment: When you use prepared statements, the query is never assembled with parameters and the query and the parameters are handled separately all the time (even in DB). I am afraid that there is no way to get assembled query other than doing it by yourself (which I would not recommend, because it is hard to implemented it in a secure way)

Comment: The reason why i wanted to use prepared statements was to let automatically mask the inputs (against SQL injection). But i noticed that my usage of `$qb->expr()->literal($myval)` also masks the input by its own way. I hope this masking is- and rests enough secure. Upvoted your answer because of clarification.